# Will getting the citation format minorly incorrect cost me?

Tags: citations, citation-style

I recently submitted a graded essay with the Harvard citation format and did not know that for single authored papers, the in-text citation follows as Last Name (Year) when starting a sentence or using it within a sentence. I accidentally used the full name instead for a few of my citations but have referenced every single citation in my bibliography.

Will this minor error cost me a lot? Is it plagiarism if I have gotten this wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Plagiarism is when you take something written by someone else without attribution. That has certainly not happened here.

My best guess for what will happen is something between "literally nothing" and "almost nothing," depending on whether perfect referencing was a specific outcome to be assessed on the essay. It is, at worst, an incredibly minor, forgivable, understandable mistake. Don't worry about it.

Comment: At worst, an editor of a publication would correct it or ask you to. No one can predict what a professor would do and someone very picky about formalities might mark you down a bit.  But you could also be proactive and tell the professor about the error, offering to correct it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I could definitely do that as well, and possibly should, but since there was a deadline for the essay and its been overshot, I don't think I'll be able to do so since the grading system is anonymous and the essay was submitted via Moodle.